# DOM update inside IFRAME scrolls wrapper element to top

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, ios8, safari

I have a host application that's loading a guest application inside an iframe. The iframe, in turn, is wrapped inside a div with overflow-y set to auto so it will scroll the guest application if it overflows.

On iOS 8, if anything in the DOM of the guest application is updated, the scrolling element hosting the iframe jumps to the top and is sometimes unresponsive to scrolling for a few seconds.

I set up a sample page to see this issue in action. View it from an iOS 8 device: http://jonathantower.github.io/

This sample hosts a page inside a full-screen iframe and scrolls it as described above. It also updates the first paragraph to a random number every 5 seconds. If you scroll the number off screen on iOS 8, you will see it jump within 5 seconds. Note that this does not occur in other browsers.

Comment: I usually have to scroll the number a ways off the screen. If it's just barely off, it doesn't always happen. You can scroll to the bottom of the page and it will definitely happen.

Comment: Anybody have any thought on this?

Comment: Anyone: what's the appropriate way to nudge a question like this when it's had to response in 4 days?

Comment: I logged this as a bug with Apple, but I'd love to hear anyone's ideas on how to work around this in the mean time.